# GraphQL returning wrong data on PayloadCMS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, graphql, payload

Getting started with PayloadCMS. With database on mongo, a document contains, among other fields, these:

`filename: "some_file.wav" url: "http://localhost:3000/pieces-files/some_file.webm"`

But when fetching, I get the wrong url:

`url: "http://localhost:3000/pieces-files/some_file.wav"`

Query used is:

```
query Piece($slug: String, $draft: Boolean) {
    Pieces(where: { slug: { equals: $slug }}, limit: 1, draft: $draft) {
      docs {
        id
        title
        filename
        url
        mimeType
        filesize
        composer
        album
        year
        label
        format
        description
        categories {
          title
        }
        createdAt
        user {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Why may this be like this?

There is only one document in this collection, and all other fields are returned correctly.

Curiously, if I change the variables of the query and instead search by url, like so:

`Pieces(where: { url: { equals: $url }}, limit: 1, draft: $draft) { ...`

I can only find the document if the url matches the one with .webm. If the query searches for .wav, then no docs are found.

I have tested this from inside the payload project and from postman, same results.

Comment: You need to show your resolver code from the server - that's where the problem(s) lie.

Comment: Hi @MichelFloyd apologies for my ignorance, but where would I find the resolver code?

Comment: On your serve you must have some code that *resolves* the `Pieces` query by actually querying Mongo.

Comment: I am trying to find such thing in a Payload CMS project, are you familiar with this framework and would be able to point out something?

Comment: Regrettably no.